# How to add an PHP IF statement in this Script?

Tags: php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM item";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$data['result_2'] .= '
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="content-boxes style-two top-column clearfix animated flipInY" style="opacity: 1;">
            <div class="content-boxes-text">
                <form action="php/additem.php" method="post" class="form-inline pull-right">
                    <h4>'.$row['itemName'].'</h4><input type="hidden" name="itemName" value="'.$row['itemName'].'">
                    <img src="../wholesale/img/sourdough.jpg" class="img-reponsive">
                    <p>'.$row['description'].'</p><input type="hidden" name="description" value="'.$row['description'].'">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Qty</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="How Many?">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- //.content-boxes-text -->
        </div>
        <!-- //.content-boxes -->
    </div>
';
}
```

I want to be able to add an if statement in this result_2 string. 
This is for displaying a product, and i would like to display price depending on users session value?
eg.

```
if ($_SESSION['customer_x'] == a) {
    display price a
}
else if ($_SESSION['customer_x'] == b) {
    display price b
}
```

Is this the correct method to be able to add an if statement to a JSON query?

Comment: If you want to display different prices based on the value of `$__SESSION['customer_x']`, then you can just assign the price to a variable (say `$display_price`) in your above `if-else` statement. And use the variable in your long string of HTML. But where does `price a` and `price b` come from? `$row `?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After Starting your while loop, put a if else there,

```
$price ="";
if ($__SESSION['customer_x'] == a) {
   $price='display price a';
}
else if ($_SESSION['customer_x'] == b) {
  $price='display price b';
}
```

and now echo this price where ever you want to in your html

this is more neet and less messy way

Comment: I initially thought this would work too but the code breaks when i add this :/

Comment: No it wont i tested it, put the code just after starting your while, After  that start your html content

Comment: Actually this worked after i set the A and B as a string eg, 'A' 'B'
Thanks

Comment: Gud, happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [ternary if operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) to have conditional statements inside strings, example

```
$bool = false;
echo "The value of \$bool is " . ($bool == true ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");
```

[Example in use](http://3v4l.org/8DVP9)

Answer (score 1):

To add that you can keep doing the same but:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ // the next of the content
    $priceOfSession = ($__SESSION['customer_x'] == a) ? 'pricea' : 'priceb';
      $data['result_2'] .= '
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4"> 
             '.$priceOfSession.' 
                </div>
             </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <!-- //.content-boxes-text -->
    </div>
</div>
```

';
}

So if you want to evaluate only two conditions if otherwise the if you want, simply add it there. Do as you add the $ row but before defining value.